# Rhino Licensing

Tags: .net, rhino-licensing

I am trying to develop a licensing system using Rhino-Licensing. I downloaded [Rhino.Licensing.dll](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-licensing) and added reference into my project. I'm trying to run [this](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/rhino-licensing/) example. 
I generated `license.xml` but there's execption in the app that use this license:

```
...
using Rhino.Licensing;
...
 static void Main()
 {
  var publicKey = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\publicKey.xml");

   new LicenseValidator(publicKey, @"c:\license.xml").AssertValidLicense();

   Console.WriteLine("Hello");
   Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

`{"Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821"}`

My questions are: Is this correct way for adding Rhino-Licensing into project and why i get this exception? I think this `log4net.dll` is in added `Rhino.Licensing.dll`.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4):

Rhino Licensing has a dependency on log4net.  Add a reference to log4net to your project so that it is deployed with your application.  You'll likely need version 1.2.10.0 specifically as the "latest" is 1.2.13...

## Update:

As an alternative, you could probably reference the Rhino Licensing nuget package; it should get all the dependencies you need.  http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rhino.Licensing/

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. Problem was in wrong formated `license.xml`. `Rhino.Licensing.dll` have itself log4net reference.